# Map an Azure #Root to my custom subdomain's root

Tags: azure-storage

From [MS's docs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/) I find a passage that suggests I can map a custom subdomain to it's root level:

> Default URL: http://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myblob or
>   http://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$root/myblob
>
> Custom domain URL: http://www.contoso.com/myblob or
>   http://www.contoso.com/$root/myblob

I've stepped thru the DNS CNAME procedures and can hit a blob that's contained *inside* one of my blob containers but not at the root.

In other words, with a file named '**hitme.wmv**' sitting in the $root of the storage account named **MyStorage** (and the appropriate dns configuration completed) I expect this URL to work:

> http://myCustomSub.myDomain.com/hitme.wmv

and not event the fully qualified path:

> http://myCustomSub.myDomain.com/$root/hitme.wmv

If I try a file in a BlobContainer (instead of $root) the URL works:

> http://myCustomSub.myDomain.com/My2ndTierContainer/hitme.wmv

But I want the shortest URL possible.

thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be due to the $Root set to private. I adjusted it and now I have the behavior I expected.